# CountdownTimer is not working as intended (wrong time)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-date, android-timer

I'm using `CountdownTimer` in my app to display remaining time until specific `Date`. But `Date` is only 2 hours from current time, but if I convert `millisUntilFinished` to hours, it says 9 hours. `Date` is in UTC format.

```
remainingTimer = object : CountDownTimer(dateTime.time, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                remTime = millisUntilFinished
                notifyChanged(PAYLOAD_UPDATE_REM_TIME)
            }

            override fun onFinish() {
                swapTimers()
            }

        }.start()

val hours = ((remTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)).rem(24))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to specify timer time for how long **(2 hour from now = 2*60*60*1000 millis)** you want to run
    if you convert date in millis its not gonna work the way you want as it return date in millis,

```
remainingTimer = object : CountDownTimer(2*60*60*1000, 1000) {
                override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
                    remTime = millisUntilFinished
                    notifyChanged(PAYLOAD_UPDATE_REM_TIME)
                }

                override fun onFinish() {
                    swapTimers()
                }

            }.start()

    val hours = ((remTime / (1000 * 60 * 60)).rem(24))
```